# Passing uniform values to into vertex and fragment shaders

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, qt3d, pyside2

How to pass an uniform value into vertex and fragment shaders?

I know that something like that is possible in `QMaterial`:

```py
self.colorParameter = Qt3DRender.QParameter("color", color)
self.addParameter(self.colorParameter)
```

Is there any other way?

My goal is to pass some uniform values and change them from time to time.

Comment: [`glUniform*()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) not working for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault thanks for the comment. No, I am using `qt3d`, I cannot use this.

Comment: Have a look at the already implemented materials by At at https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/5.11/src/extras/defaults. This should show you how to pass parameters to shaders.

Comment: Thank you again, @Florian Blume. Now it works!

Comment: I'm glad it works :) Post your answer below for other people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Florian Blume suggested, I am posting my answer:

```py
class MyMaterial(Qt3DRender.QMaterial):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # some code ...

        self.parameter_position = Qt3DRender.QParameter("position", QVector3D(0, 0, 0))
        self.addParameter(self.parameter_position)

    def update_position(self, position):
        self.removeParameter(self.parameter_position)
        self.parameter_position.setValue(position)
        self.addParameter(self.parameter_position)
```